# GeckoFx can only be called from the same thread on which it was initialized (normally the UI thread). SynchronizationContext does not work

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, user-interface, geckofx

This is my class GeckoBrowserForm

```
namespace NCrawler.GeckoProcessor
{
    public partial class GeckoBrowserForm : Form
    {
        #region Readonly & Static Fields

        private static bool s_IsXulrunnerInitialized;
        private readonly GeckoWebBrowser m_GeckoWebBrowser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
        private readonly string m_Url;
        private SynchronizationContext m_uiContext;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        static GeckoBrowserForm()
        {   
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        }

        public GeckoBrowserForm(string xulRunnerPath, string url)
        {
            m_uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            if (m_uiContext == null)
            {
                m_uiContext = new SynchronizationContext();
            }

            InitializeXulRunner(xulRunnerPath);
            m_Url = url;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Location = new Point(0, 0);
            Size = new Size(800, 800);
            Done = false;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Instance Properties

        public string DocumentDomHtml { get; set; }
        public Boolean Done { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Instance Methods

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {   
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            // lets see the thread id
            int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            Trace.WriteLine("Run thread: " + id);

            m_uiContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(_ =>
            {
                m_GeckoWebBrowser.Parent = this;
                m_GeckoWebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                m_GeckoWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, ee) =>
                {
                    GeckoHtmlElement element = null;
                    var geckoDomElement = m_GeckoWebBrowser.Document.DocumentElement;
                    if (geckoDomElement != null && geckoDomElement is GeckoHtmlElement)
                    {
                        element = (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoDomElement;
                        DocumentDomHtml = element.InnerHtml;
                    }
                };

                m_GeckoWebBrowser.Navigate(m_Url);
            }), null);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Class Methods

        private static void InitializeXulRunner(string path)
        {
            if (s_IsXulrunnerInitialized)
            {
                return;
            }

            s_IsXulrunnerInitialized = true;
            Xpcom.Initialize(path);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

but `DoWork` method get an excpetion

> GeckoFx can only be called from the same thread on which it was
>   initialized (normally the UI thread)

I have read that I need to use `SynchronizationContext` but it is the same. Still the same error. I am ceating a form in some other project with

```
GeckoBrowserForm geckoBrowserForm = new GeckoBrowserForm(XulRunnerPath, Uri.ToString()))
geckoBrowserForm.Show();
```

and it is inside thread so I want to have `5 browsers`.

What can I do? Is `SynchronizationContext` correct implemented?

Comment: Browsers, like any large chunk of software, are not thread-safe.  So get ahead by not using a thread.  They are not needed, the Navigate() call takes just a few milliseconds.  Then it trundles for a while in the background.  And lets you know it is done by firing the DocumentCompleted event.

Comment: I need more threads because of performance

Comment: are all your "new GeckoBrowserForm(..)" calls done on the same thread?

Comment: does your main entry point have the STAThread attribute?

Comment: Tom no "new GeckoBrowserForm(..)" are not done on the same thread that way is problem i think. And yes I set STAThread  on threads

Comment: I think that problem is with Xpcom.Initialize(path);